# FreeForm Pro Notifications

Tags: solspace-freeform

I have a job application form using FreeForm Pro.  The form displays multiple fields, and has 6 hidden fields (which are all set up as custom fields in the Freeform CP).  Three of those fields are pulled from an {embed} file which grabs information from a related playa field.  When I view the source code for the form, everything is populated.  However, I have two issues that I'm dealing with.

First, some of those hidden fields aren't showing their values in the notification emails.  So the notification email is showing Phone: {recruiter_phone} rather than putting the phone number in.  Again, the source code has the correct values, and when I view the entry in the CP it is populated.

Next, I need to figure out a way to update the admin_cc_notify="name@domain.com" based on the email address that is being pulled in the {embed file} for the recruiter.  The idea is that, when someone applies for a position, the recruiter will be notified.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Todd

Comment: There are really two questions here... Can you split into two?  I'm having the same problem as you in question 1

Comment: See if this is the fix for your first question: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/34278/freeform-email-notification-variables-fail-to-parse/34280#34280